# how to remove href on onmouseout?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have tried for hours looking in this site, but nothing fixes my problem w/ onmouseout.
My onmouseover works great w/c i got the idea from this site too and made it work.

```
 onmouseover="this.href = 'urlHere';"
```

my onmousever is ok but the real problem is my onmouseout.

```
  echo '<td><a onmouseover="this.href=\'main_db.php?page='.$iii_LV.'\'" onmouseout=""> '.$rows_LV['product_id'].'</a></td>';
```

to give you an idea of what i'm trying to do, these are some part of the whole code which i made:

```
while($rows_LV = mysql_fetch_array($result_LV))
{
++$i_LV;
if ($i_LV%2 == 0) 
 {$colorb="#99CFFF";}
else
 {$colorb="#FFFFFF";};
$iii_LV=$i_LV+$ii_LV;
echo '<tr bgcolor='.$colorb.' onmouseover=" mOver(this)" onmouseout=" mOut(this)" >';
echo '<td><a onmouseover="this.href=\'main_db.php?page='.$iii_LV.'\'" onmouseout=""> '.$rows_LV['product_id'].'</a></td>';
echo "<td> ".$rows_LV['name']."</a></td>";
echo "<td> ".$rows_LV['category']."</a></td>";
echo "<td> ".$rows_LV['cost']."</a></td>";
echo "<td> ".$rows_LV['retail']."</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
};
```

Any help would be great & thanks in advance....

Comment: What have you tried? At the moment there is no javascript in your `onmouseout` event handler.

Comment: onmouseout="this.href = ""

Comment: @jeroen onmouseout, href attrib is not removed so i can see a lot of underlined 'product_id' after onmouseover...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually do anything on onmouseout .. do you mean to do:

```
this.href = ''
```

Note that clicking on an empty `href` may actually return the page, so you would have to use `.removeAttribute`.

Since you have [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), it would be better to bind the events separately, and you get more flexibility too:

```
$('a').hover(
   function () {
      $(this).attr('href', 'urlHere');
   },
   function () {
      $(this).removeAttr('href');
   }
);
```

Comment: i got your answer thanks & sorry for my noobness on jquery but it doesnt work... Can you pls. be more specific on the syntax on what should i put **onmouseout=""** i mean, how do i exactly put _.removeAttribute **onmouseout**?

Comment: onmouseout="this.removeAttribute(\'href\')"   thanks for all the replies, it took me some time to figure it out since some of the solutions given were not that specific. I'm still new to jquery/javascript. again sorry! Anyways, this code is a bit shorter & got the result that i wanted... But then again thanks to all who helped out